# rosdoc_lite doesn't find modules

Tags: ros, python, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I'm fairly new to both Python and ROS and I reached a point where I'm supposed to document my code.
I'm programming a Baxter robot and while programming with Python isn't much of a trouble, generating the documentation currently is.

So what I did is the following:

- Read this site and follow it's steps including 3.1 -> http://wiki.ros.org/Sphinx
- Lose ;-)

Jokes aside, I'm getting warnings in this style:

```
/home/ies-labor/devel/baxter_ws/src/baxter_ies_sdk/doc/Baxter.rst:4: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'Baxter'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 335, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named Baxter
```

My sources are found in /package/src and there are several files like Baxter.py, BaxterArm.py etc.
For each of them I receive an error.
I also get warnings about each of the source files' .rst file:

```
/home/ies-labor/devel/baxter_ws/src/baxter_ies_sdk/doc/Baxter.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

At the end no documentation is produced except the index template.
The folders .build, .static and .templates are empty.

My workstation is using Ubuntu 14.04.2 with kernel 3.13.0-49 and ROS release used is Indigo.

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207161/rosdoc_lite-doesn%27t-find-modules/) by [Morv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22170/morv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This page](http://wiki.ros.org/Sphinx) explains most of what is needed to use Spinx with `rosdoc_lite`. It should probably be easier to find. Suggestions for making that easier are welcome.

It is hard to tell exactly where your documentation is failing. If you still have trouble after following the directions above, please post more details by editing your question.

**EDIT:** Standard ROS practice is to place Python modules under the `src/your_package` subdirectory or your package, making the top-level module name the same as your package. Python requires that directory to have an `__init__.py` file, too.

See: [the catkin Python howto](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22170/morv/) on 2015-04-17**:
Although I welcome an answer, I already read that page as described above including the link and url.
So i did exactly follow the directions given on that site but it sure fails, that's why I am asking. I'd rather have it working wihtout problem but it simply won't.

Thanks so far.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-04-17**:
Are your Python modules are in `/home/ies-labor/devel/baxter_ws/src/baxter_ies_sdk/src` or in `.../src/baxter_ies_sdk`?

**Comment by [Morv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22170/morv/) on 2015-04-21**:
They're in the first path. baxter_ws is catkin root workspace, baxter_ies_sdk among others are catkin sub workspaces.
May this be a problem? The generation of the eclipse project didn't like the sub workspaces either. I had to create a project inside of the root workspace.

Sorry for the late answer

**Comment by [Morv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22170/morv/) on 2015-04-21**:
Okay. It was my own fault. I'm fairly new to ROS and the whole catkin stuff and also I'm the only one working at it at my department.
The reason it didn't work was the wrong placement of my source files. They have to be placed in packages with **init**.py just as you said.

Now it's working, thanks.